# Generate a XML layout file dynamically

Tags: android, xml, forms, layout, android-activity

In my current spring project, one of my activities should be a form where the user can insert a new entity. the code for the activity is like this:

```
public class FormNewItemActivity extends Activity {
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.form_new_item_view);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Dao<?> dao = intent.getStringExtra(HelloActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
  }
}
```

the layout file should have a list of EditText fields and a unique Button in the end for trigger the saving of the data in a SQLite database.

I wonder if it's possible, giving a list of string with the name of the fields of the entity class, generate a xml layout file dynamically with one EditText for each field.

Anyone knows if this is really possible and how can be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot dynamically create and load an XML layout file. However, what you can do is dynamically create the layout programatically which will have the same effect. This method works by creating and adding views at runtime to a layout that serves as a container - such as an empty `LinearLayout`. In your example you would make R.layout.form_new_item_view contain an empty `LinearLayout`

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/container_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"/>
```

You would then find your container layout in onCreate

```
    LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.container_layout);
```

And then create and add `TextView` or `EditText` as you needed from a list of field names

```
    for(String title: listOfTitles){
        TextView field = new TextView(this);
        field.setText(title);
        container.addView(field); 
    }
```

To customize the layout further you can set `LayoutParams` for each view added to control margins and other parameters.

Comment: Hello @Rarw , is it possible through writing some script or anything in gradle file(may be groovy script) or anything? Please help me, if you know anything about it.